# azure devops shows 'set up build' button

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, multibranch-pipeline

I am using git service of azure devops.
I have my build pipeline setup with master branch using yml file.
And it runs & perform well.
Question is on Azure UI: Why does it show me the button 'Set up build' i already have my pipeline setup.

The reason is that the latest commit did not trigger my pipeline as we are excluding build trigger for README file changes.
(Build status links with commit id)
is there anyway to show the latest build status instead of this button.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens if we commit some files which is part of exclusion in pipeline trigger, as in this particular commit there is no pipeline status is linked.

Answer (score 1):

Azure DevOps provides this quick way to set up yaml pipeline using this “Set up build” button when new repository is created. When you click this button to set up yaml pipeline and queue a new build, this button will show you the latest build's state( **the build status is linked with commit-id**), as below.

[image]

To your situation, as this [ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1301185/set-up-build-button-should-not-be-visi.html) suggested, you could see the build status in the other place, such as Commits hub, Dashboad, build status badges and so on.